# How to declare optional function argument with empty array default value in VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, optional-arguments

I am trying to build the routine below. The last argument of the routine is an optional array, by default it should have two empty strings. The declaration below doesn't work, it gives me this error: Compile error: Constant expression required

```
Public Sub CreateReport(rpt As Report, rptSelectFLDS As Variant, _
                        rptWhereConds As Dictionary, _
                        Optional rptTopSelect As Variant = Array("", ""))
```

Answer (score 3):

How about just checking to see if the argument `IsMissing()`?

```
Public Sub CreateReport(rpt As Report, rptSelectFLDS As Variant, _
                        rptWhereConds As Dictionary, _
                        Optional rptTopSelect As Variant)

    If IsMissing(rptTopSelect) Then rptTopSelect = Array("", "")
```

Comment: yes, it is a possible work around. But I am being curious, is there no way to set a default value for an optional array argument? Maybe  it's doable but my syntax is bad.

Comment: Honestly, I'm just as curious. I'm just not sitting in front of my machine at the moment.

Comment: I've done some digging around and the answer is no. You can not set a default value in the signature line because it expects a constant expression. All you can do is check to see if the variant is missing. I suppose you could fake an overload with a second function, but that seems convoluted.

Comment: Ok, add that to your answer and I'll mark it as correct